# Set third item in ListView other size

Tags: android, listview, fonts

Hello I have a Navigation Drawer and want to set the third item of the drawer listview in a other textsize. Is there a way without creating an Adapter and just work with this piece of code:

```
    mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles_array);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mTitles));
```

And how can I change the font to this one in my assets folder?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe you will have to use an adapter as there is nothing that is going to help you with listview at all or if so, efficiently, as nothing in the api [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) looks to support it. I would try going [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) and looking the tutorial and example, it is a phenomenal one. Also you could look to googles provided example for help [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

EDIT: from experience with my own app I'm pretty sure this will be your best bet, especially for future implementations.